# PowerShell - How to achieve this logic as in bash command line { A ; { B && C ;} ;}

Tags: powershell, one-liner

I am trying to achieve a specific logic in **PowerShell** **1-liner** that is similar to the following bash command:

`{ $another_command_group ;} && { A ; { B && C ;} ;} && { $another_command_group ;}`

> { A ; { B && C ;} ;}

The logic of this command is as follows:

1. A=0, B=0, C=0, then it will execute nothing, and this Command Group will return a 0
2. A=0, B=0, C=1, then it will execute nothing, and this Command Group will return a 0
3. A=0, B=1, C=0, then it will execute Command B only, and this Command Group will return a 0
4. A=0, B=1, C=1, then it will execute Command B and Command C, and this Command Group will return a 1
5. A=1, B=0, C=0, then it will execute Command A only, and this Command Group will return a 0
6. A=1, B=0, C=1, then it will execute Command A only, and this Command Group will return a 0
7. A=1, B=1, C=0, then it will execute Command A and Command B, and this Command Group will return a 0
8. A=1, B=1, C=1, then it will execute All Command A, B, C, and this Command Group will return a 1

---

PowerShell version: 7.26

OS: Windows

What I already tried:

- `( A ; ( B && C ) )`

  Not Working.

> | Missing closing ')' in expression.

- `A ; ( B && C )`

  Worked though, but apparently this is not good enough, because I need the Parentheses `()` to make them a `(group)` to stick with other `(group)s` with `AND &&`

---

I am having trouble finding a **one-liner Command** to replicate this logic in **PowerShell**. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Did you try curly brackets instead of parenthesis? You need both curly brackets and parenthesis in PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A *single* pipeline chain, i.e. two or more possibly pipeline-connected commands connected via `&&` or `||`, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators) needs *no* enclosure - except situationally in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) if *clarifying precedence* is necessary.

  - For instance, `{ B && C ;}` in your Bash code can be represented as `B && C`, or, if needed for precedence clarification, `(B && C)` (note that, unlike in Bash, `(...)` does *not* create a *subshell* in PowerShell).
- To execute *multiple statements* (a pipeline chain being one example of a statement) as a group, enclose them in a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), `{ ... }` *and also* call that block with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) or, if needed, for PowerShell code, with `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).

  - That is, `{ ... }` *alone* does *not* result in execution - it just defines a reusable piece of PowerShell code that must be *called on demand*.
  - Also, unlike in Bash, the last statement inside `{ ... }` need *not* be `;`-terminated; `;` need only be placed *between* statements.
  - Unfortunately, unlike in Bash, **a script-block call does *not* preserve the success status of the last command executed inside of it**, which in turn means that **script-block calls can *not* meaningfully participate in a pipeline chain, because they *invariably* signal *success*.**
  - This applies analogously to script *files* (`*.ps1`) as well, which, however, can signal success vs. failure via an explicit [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords) statement, whose use is *not* an option in a script *block* (it would exit the script / session as a whole). While [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#return) can be used to exit a script block, its purpose - unlike in Bash - is to *output data*, not to report an exit code.

Therefore, unfortunately, a hypothetical pipeline chain involving *script-block calls* (the analog of a *group command* in Bash (POSIX-compatible shells)) **must be broken up into *multiple* statements involving tests of the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)**, which *does* reflect the exit code of the most recent external-program / script-file call:

```bash
& { $another_command_group }
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { & { A ; B && C } }
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { & { $another_command_group } }
```

However, as you've discovered yourself - **if practical - you can *reformulate* a script-block call to a *logically equivalent single pipeline chain***, whose success status *does* work as expected.

The example you provided is that `& { A ; (B && C) }` (which itself is the loose analog of command group `{ A ; { B && C ;} ;}` from your Bash command) can be reformulated as a single pipeline chain as follows:

```bash
( ( A && B && C ) || ( B && C ) )
```

The above preserves the success status of whatever program executes last, and can therefore be used as-is in a larger pipeline chain.